# Set the width of Spinner using java not referencing any xml

Tags: java, android

I am dynamically building a `View` here is what I have so far:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);     

Spinner s = new Spinner(this);
s.setId(1);
List<SpinnerObject> list = this.datasource.getFacilitiesList();
ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
ll.addView(s);
setContentView(sv);
```

How do I set the width of my `Spinner`. I would like to know how to set it to `wrap_content` and a set value like `200dp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of anything in code by adjusting its `LayoutParams`. 
For example:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.width = 200dp;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: i just used `s.setLayoutParams(new Spinner.LayoutParams(-2,-1));`